# sscanf: Which additional characters I have to consider in order to get to the correct value?

Tags: c, character, scanf

This is the code to scan the information below regarding **/proc/cpuinfo** (and it works). Using `%*s` I can skip storing specific columns for each row. So after skipping 5 times I can store the `vendor_id`. But why I have to skip 4 times to get the cpu family afterwards?

```
{
    int fd = open("/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    int length = read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    
    sscanf(buffer, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %s %*s %*s %*s %s %*s %*s %s",
           vendor_id, cpu_family, cpu_model);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't skip 4 times, you skip 3 times. One for `cpu`, one for `family`, and one for `:`.

Comment: You might find [libcpuid](https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid) interesting, as an alternative to parsing `/proc/cpuinfo` (and which works on other operating systems as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal with a single `sscanf()` call but it is more complicated:

- you must null terminate the buffer because `read` will not add a null terminator;
- you must skip full lines, not just words;
- you must skip the legend (or you might match it);
- you should protect the destination arrays to avoid undefined behavior
- you should test for proper parsing.

```
// get CPU info into 3 char arrays of at least 100 bytes.
// returns -1 on error, 0 
int get_info(char vendor_id[100], char cpu_family[100], char cpu_model[100]) {
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int fd = open("/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY);
    int length;

    if (fd < 0)
        return -1;

    length = read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE - 1);
    close(fd);
    if (length <= 0)
        return -1;

    buffer[length] = '\0';    
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[^\n] "           // skip the processor line
                       "%*[^:]: %99[^\n] "  // skip the legend and parse vendor_id
                       "%*[^:]: %99[^\n] "  // skip the legend and parse cpu family
                       "%*[^:]: %99[^\n]",  // skip the legend and parse model
                       vendor_id, cpu_family, cpu_model) != 3) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```